# Discord.Js TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am currently trying to create an inventory command where users can check what types of items they have. however i am currently receiving an error stating: (TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined) at line 7.

Here is the following code:

```
module.exports = {
name: "inv",
description: "show the inventory!",
permissions: [],
cooldown: 30,
async execute(message, args, client, Discord, profileData, user, userQuery){
let temp_items = await user.inventory.map(item => item.name);
let items = [];

temp_items.forEach(itemName => {
  if(!items.find(v => v.name === itemName)){
    items.push({
      amount: temp_items.filter(temp_item => temp_item === itemName).length,
      name: itemName
    });
  }
});

items = items.map(item => `**${item.name}** x\`${item.amount}\``)

  const inventory = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setTitle("Inventory")
    .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL())
    .setDescription(`${items.join('\n\t')}`)
  await message.channel.send(inventory);

 }
}
```

Comment: `user.inventory` is returning undefined, trace your steps back to where you define it

Comment: the user. inventory is leading back to the profile schema for the MongoDB database. basically user is the variable i use to set up a profile for a user and inventory is the name of a property in the profile schema itself. however if i console.log the user.inventory it doesn't return undefined for me